# Usar informacion de una tabla PHP en otra pagina

Tags: php

tengo un sistema PHP en donde genero una tabla mediante una consulta SQL, esta tabla muestra la informacion de los empleados: ID, nombre y el nombre del archivo de su fotografia. Esta informacion la quiero utilizar para, en otra pagina, generar un archivo PDF donde se muestre su nombre, su foto y su cumpleaños. Lo que quiero es que al dar clic a la fila con la informacion del empleado, el dato del ID de ese empleado se pase a la segunda pagina donde se genera el PDF, y mediante una consulta basandose en el ID de la tabla, sacar la informacion del empleado.

Este es el codigo de la tabla:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Empleados</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=empleados', 'root', ''); 
?>
<table class="table table-striped">
    
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>NOMBRE</th>
            <th>FOTO</th>
            <th>VER</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
<?php foreach ($link->query('SELECT * from fotos') as $row){  ?> 
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['ID']   ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['NOMBRE'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['filename'] ?></td>
    <td><a href="/TCPDF/examples/example_051.php?NOMINA=<? echo $row['ID'];?>">VIEW</a></td>
 </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Y este es la parte del codigo de la segunda pagina, donde quiero usar la informacion del ID de la tabla, cambiando el 3486 por el ID:

```
// set document information
$pdf->setCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->setAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->setTitle('TCPDF Example 051');
$pdf->setSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->setKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
include('../tabla.php');

$servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "empleados";
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        $sql1="SELECT nombre FROM `fotos` WHERE NOMINA = '3486'";
        $query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
        $someString = $row[0];
        $sql2="SELECT filename FROM `fotos` WHERE NOMINA = '3486'";
        $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
        $row2 = mysqli_fetch_row($query2);
        $someString2 = $row2[0];

        $sql3="SELECT dian FROM `fotos` WHERE NOMINA = '3486'";
        $query3 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);
        $row3 = mysqli_fetch_row($query3);
        $someString3 = $row3[0];
        $sql4="SELECT mesn FROM `fotos` WHERE NOMINA = '3486'";
        $query4 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql4);
        $row4 = mysqli_fetch_row($query4);
        $someString4 = $row4[0];



// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->setDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->setMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->setHeaderMargin(0);
$pdf->setFooterMargin(0);

// remove default footer
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->setAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->setFont('calibri', '', 48);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// Print a text
$subtable = '<table border="1" cellspacing="6" cellpadding="4"><tr><td><h1 style="font-size: 45px;text-align:left;"><br><br><br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$someString4.'</h1></td></tr><tr><td><h1 style="font-size: 150px;text-align:LEFT;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$someString3.'</h1></td></tr></table>';

$html = '
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="7" border="1" style="text-align:center;">


<tr style="position:absolute; left:780px; top:120px;">
<td>'.$subtable.'</td>
    <td><br><br><img src="images/'.$someString2.'" border="0" height="300" width="200" align="bottom" /><h2 style="font-size: 30px;">'.$someString.'</h2></td>
</tr>


</table>';
```

Gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: ¿Quieres enviar todos los datos que recolectaste en la tabla o solo el id? En cualquier, lo que podrias hacer es enviar estos datos por GET, concatenandolos en direccion URL de la pagina donde generas el PDF

Comment: Según esto: `example_051.php?NOMINA=`, podrás encontrar el dato que necesitas mediante `$_GET['NOMINA']`, por ejemplo: `$id=$_GET['NOMINA'] ?? NULL;`, luego puedes verificar que el dato no esté vacío con `if($id) { //Aquí lanzar la consulta y crear los datos } else { //El dato está vacío, hacer otra cosa }` Por cierto, no tiene sentido enviar varias consultas a la misma tabla, puedes hacer algo así: `SELECT col1, col2, col3, col999 FROM tabla WHERE ...` y luego recuperar `col1`, `col2`, `col3` y `col999`

Comment: Muchas gracias por el apoyo, si en efecto, ya funciono con el $_GET